# SQL Server : create unique key BUT one of the columns could have several values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `Accounts` table, and I'm having problems with duplicated accounts being created in two calls to the WS at the same time.

What I'm trying to do is to add a unique key to the table `Account`, where `Identification_Type`, `Identification_Number` and `Account_Status` should not be duplicated.

But the problem is, I can have several accounts with the same `Identification_Type` and `Identification_Number`, only if they have `Account_Status = Closed`, `Rejected` or `Expired`. And that's ok.

What I can't have is more than one account if the status is `Created`, `Pending`, `Enabled`, `Inabilited`.

I want to prevent an account to be created if there is already one with the `Status = Created`, `Pending`, `Enabled`, `Inabilited`.

Is there a way to create a Unique Key or something in SQL with this restriction?

I will put an example of what I want to prevent.

Table Account:

Identification_Type | Identification_Number | Account_Status

---------1-----------------------12345678-----------------Closed
---------1-----------------------12345678-----------------Closed
---------1-----------------------12345678-----------------Rejected
---------1-----------------------12345678-----------------Closed
---------1-----------------------12345678-----------------Expired
---------**1**-----------------------**12345678**-----------------**Created**

And, as there is already an `Account` in `Account_Status = Created` I want to add a Unique Key to prevent to add another one in `Account_Status = Created`, `Pending`, `Enabled` or `Inabilited`.

I can't have more than one `Account` in `Account_Status = Created`, `Pending`, `Enabled` or `Inabilited` for the same combination of `Identification_Type` | `Identification_Number`, but I can have several for the other status.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to be unique, but the answer to your question is a *filtered unique index*.

Something like this:

```
create unique index unq_accounts_filtered
    on accounts(Identification_Type, Identification_Number)
    where account_status in ('Created', 'Pending', 'Enabled', 'Inabilited');
```

This prevents only account with those statuses.  You may also want:

```
create unique index unq_accounts_3
    on accounts(Identification_Type, Identification_Number, account_status);
```

To prevent duplicates with the same status.  On the other hand, this might not be desirable if multiples can be `closed`, for instance.

Comment: Didn't work. I made a test table and I couldn't add the index you gave me. The error says: The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Account' and the index name 'unq_accounts_filtered'. The duplicate key value is (1, 12345678). I think I didnt explain very well, I will edit question adding more explanation

Comment: Dude, that error message perfectly explains that you already have duplicate data in your table. Eliminate the duplicates first and create index as explained.